# styled maps and places library Google Map API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

How can I get results from the Google Places library to show up on my styled Google Maps?  With this code I just get the styled map, no places.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>  


<script type="text/javascript">


 function initialize() {
var styles = [ { featureType: "road.arterial", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [ {   color: "#808080" }, { weight: 0.5 } ] },{ featureType: "road.arterial", elementType: "labels.text.stroke", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" }, { color: "#fafafa" } ] },{ featureType: "water", elementType: "geometry", stylers: [ { color: "#b4d2fa" } ] },{ featureType: "water", elementType: "geometry.fill", stylers: [ { color: "#9c3239" } ] } ]

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
{name: "WATS Map"});

var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3068, -83.681)

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 12,
center: myLatLng,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
  mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
}
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
mapOptions);


map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');


var request = {
      location: myLatLng,
      radius: 1500,
      types: ['store']
    };
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: styledMap,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(styledMap, this);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the variable **`map`** global and assign  **`map`** to the map-option of the markers in `createMarker()`

Currently you use there `styledMap` , but this is not a map-object, it's a StyledMapType

Comment: I found the two incorrectly coded `styledMap` and corrected them.  The map variable is:
`var map = new      google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);` my understanding was that it is a global variable by default in javascript.  Is that not the case?  Thanks!

Comment: I also tried placing the map variable outside the function.  It's still not working though

Comment: I started over from scratch and managed to get it working... Thanks!

Comment: when you define a variable with the var-keyword the variable is accessible in the scope where you've defined it. In this case the scope is the function, so the variable is not global. When you ommit the var-keyword, the variable is always global, no matter where you've defined it.